# Confidence interval for function of the parameter - small sample size

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, small-sample

I am trying to come up with a solution for this problem. Consider the following set of random variables:
\begin{align*}
X_{11},...,X_{1n_{1}}\quad &\text{i.i.d. Bernoulli(1-$e^{-\lambda_{1}}$)}\\
&\vdots\\
X_{m1},...,X_{mn_{m}}\quad &\text{i.i.d. Bernoulli(1-$e^{-\lambda_{m}}$)}
\end{align*}
We assume independence between each set of r.v. and $n_{j}$, for all $j=1,...,m$, and $m$, are small quantities.

I want to create a $\alpha$-level confidence interval for the quantity $g(\lambda_{1},...,\lambda_{m})=\sum_{j=1}^{m}\lambda_{j}$.

Since I have a small sample size, I can't use any kind of asymptotic result. Moreover, I don't want to use a bootstrap approach here. I am trying to come up with a closed form solution for this confidence interval.

PS: By the invariance property of the MLE, we have $\widehat{g}(\widehat{\lambda_{1}},...,\widehat{\lambda_{m}})=\sum_{j=1}^{m}\widehat{\lambda_{j}}=-\sum_{j=1}^{m}\log(1-\overline{X}_{j})$, where $\overline{X}_{j}=\frac{1}{n_{j}}\sum_{i=1}^{n_{j}}{X}_{ji}$.

I appreciate any kind of suggestion.

Comment: I am curious why you mention the MLE in the post scriptum. As you said earlier, you don't want to use asymptotic results, and the *sole* justification for using ML lies in its asymptotic properties. I also wonder what exactly you mean by "closed form." Bootstrapping can lead to "closed form" formulas as easily as any other statistical procedure.

Comment: Right, the MLE does not help me here. And by "closed form" I meant that I am trying to avoid using resampling methods. I tried to compute this confidence interval by nonparametric bootstrap. Unless we further assume lambda very small, this approach does not seem feasible because many bootstrap samples lead to infinite values for lambda.

Comment: Is $m$ really fixed so that we can speak of a function of the
parameters? Are the $n_i$ random? Such a problem could arise from
*overdispersion*: $p(\mathbf{X}_{i}|\lambda_i)$ is iid Bernoulli, you know
$p(\lambda_i|\mu)$ where $\mu$ is a parameter shared by all samples
which you want to infer on. If so, a (hierarchical) Bayesian inference
would be nice.